# Difference between hyperparameter and heuristic in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, heuristics, hyperparameters

What is the difference between hyperparameter and heuristic in the context of machine learning. If you are not learning the parameter and instead deciding it in advance, doesn't that essentially act as a heuristic?

If anyone could provide a clear definition of each and a comparison that would be great! I hope I am not comparing apples to oranges in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting thought! The most clear difference between a heuristic and a hyperparameter is that the heuristic is a function which is helpful in search problems, it is used to quickly weigh in different solutions, while a hyperparameter is essentially "hardcoded" in the model, thus does not help the search at all.

However, if you define a heuristic function that just returns the constant hyperparameter, then we can really say that this heuristic function is indeed the same as a hyperparameter. We usually don't view it this way though, since such a heuristic function (that always returns a constant) does not help the search of optimal parameters.